# VS Code suggestion correct but auto complete incorrect

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have my tsconfig set up with shortened paths like:

```js
"paths": { "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"], ... }
```

When I start to type an import, it correctly suggests the shortened path like in this screenshot (suggesting `$lib/stores/ErrorStore`):
[image]

But when I hit enter, the actual text that's printed is missing the `$lib`:
[image]

The path that's printed is `/stores/ErrorStore` , causing me to manually update the autocompleted text.

Does anyone know how to fix this or where I can look to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a legitimate bug:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53407

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$lib/*": ["./src/lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you have a basePath property setup. Try to add "./" before the "src/lib/*". Did you do export default the 'errorMessageStore'?

I'm assuming you are on vscode, try to restart the ts server via CTRL+SHIFT+P and type "restart ts server".

Comment: Yes I do have the baseUrl set. I tried adding the `./` to the path as suggested and that did not work. I also restarted the TS server. So, it must be something else.

Comment: You could try disabling some plugins/extensions or open the vscode without any extensions by typing  "code --disable-extensions" on your terminal. If the problem still persist, Can you change the the file name or something? Maybe there is a duplication on the files. If still I suggest you to read the [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)